# java this keyword in polymorphism

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEiMg.png)

suppose we have the following class,

```
public class poly{
static class A{
    void f(C c){System.out.println("A.f(C)");c.f(this); c.g(this);}
    static void g(){System.out.println("A.g()");}
}

static class B extends A{
    void f(D d){System.out.println("B.f(D)");d.f(this);
        ((C)d).g(this);}
    void f(C c) {System.out.println("B.f(C)");c.f(this); c.g(this);}
    static void g(){System.out.println("B.g()");}
}

static class C{
    void f(A a){System.out.println("C.f(A)");}
    static void g(A a){System.out.println("C.g(A)");}
    static void g(B b){System.out.println("C.g(B)");}
}

static class D extends C{
    void f(A a){System.out.println("D.f(A)"); }
    void f(B b){System.out.println("D.f(B)"); }
    static void g(A a){System.out.println("D.g(A)");}
    static void g(B b){System.out.println("D.g(B)");}
}
```

and the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
    D d = new D();


    a.f(d);
    a.g();
    a = b;
    c = d;
    a.f(c);
    a.f(d);
    b.f(c);
    }
}
```

i don't understand why when i call `a.f(c)` 
result will  yield 
    `D.f(A)`

complete answer is:
    `B.f(C)`
    `D.f(A)`
    `C.g(B)`

why "this" object in `c.f(this)` is object A, but object B in `c.g(this)`?

Comment: follow the execution in a debugger, if manually going through it will result in braintwists.

Comment: i do follow the execution in debugger, but it doesn't tell anything about this question.(just as my screenshot indicates...

Answer (score 0):

As clearly indicated in your image, you have defined variable "c" to be of type "C" (class C). Thus, java can't possibly know the extending class for a static code analysis. There is only 1 signature for "f" in class "C", which accepts only type "A" as a parameter. Since class "B" extends "A", you won't get a compile error, but you will call class "C"'s method of "f" since you haven't strictly defined "f" to also accept "B". Thus, you can't override any method in your subclass and java will always call the super class.

```
public class poly{
static class A{
    void f(C c){System.out.println("A.f(C)");c.f(this); c.g(this);}
    static void g(){System.out.println("A.g()");}
}

static class B extends A{
    void f(D d){System.out.println("B.f(D)");d.f(this);
        ((C)d).g(this);}
    void f(C c) {
        System.out.println("B.f(C)");
        c.f(this); <--- variable 'c' is of class "C" and has only 1 "f" function that takes in "A" (which B extends, so no compile error)
        c.g(this); <--- variable 'c' is of class "C", but both "C" and "D" have "f(B b)" defined, so use subclass "D's" method
}
    static void g(){System.out.println("B.g()");}
}

static class C{
    void f(A a){System.out.println("C.f(A)");} <--- I'm the only "f" here!
    static void g(A a){System.out.println("C.g(A)");}
    static void g(B b){System.out.println("C.g(B)");}
}

static class D extends C{
    void f(A a){System.out.println("D.f(A)"); }
    void f(B b){System.out.println("D.f(B)"); }
    static void g(A a){System.out.println("D.g(A)");}
    static void g(B b){System.out.println("D.g(B)");}
}
```

Comment: A little bit of illustration would have been better for the sake of OP. Pretty tricky following all that text.

Comment: Pretty tricky following his/her original code. But, nonetheless, I suppose a diagram would help.